# Complement of a non-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I want to prove that the complement of a non-measurable set is also not measurable.

Let $N \subset \mathbb{R}$ be non-measurable. Then $N \notin \sigma$-Algebra.

Sps. $\mathbb{R}$ \ $N$ is measurable, then $\mathbb{R}$ \ $N \in \sigma$-Algebra. But by definition of a $\sigma$-Algebra $A \in \sigma$-Algebra $\implies \mathbb{R}$ \ $A \in \sigma$-Algebra.

But this means that $\mathbb{R} \setminus(\mathbb{R} \setminus N)$ = $N \in \sigma-$Algebra. But this contradicts to our assumption that $N \notin \sigma - $Algebra.

Is this argumentation correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Are there any other ways to prove that? I'm just curious.

Comment: No, there is no other proof.

Comment: Your proof is fine in spirit, but you are inconsistent about whether you are working in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks, just edited my mistake